# How To Create Table Easily From A Join Result on Tables with Same Column/Field Names

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to do a join on 2 tables that have the same schema:

```
SELECT * FROM `tl1` INNER JOIN `tl2` ON tl1.urlid = tl2.urlid
```

This works ok, until I decide to modify the query to save it:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` SELECT * FROM `tl1` INNER JOIN `tl2` ON tl1.urlid = tl2.urlid
```

This gives an error saying that there are duplicate columns.

I have a primary key in both tables.

I found a solution by aliasing each column from each table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` SELECT tl1.id AS L_id1, tl1.filepath AS L_filepath1, tl1.urlid AS L_urlid1, tl1.fieldname AS L_fieldname1, tl1.fieldvalue AS L_fieldvalue1, tl2.id AS L_id2, tl2.filepath AS L_filepath2, tl2.urlid AS L_urlid2, tl2.fieldname AS L_fieldname2, tl2.fieldvalue AS L_fieldvalue2 FROM `tl1` INNER JOIN `tl2` ON tl1.urlid = tl2.urlid
```

However, this is tedious. What if there were 100+ columns in each table? Is there a way to make this work without having to manually aliasing each column name? I am looking for something that will make MySQL create a table with column names of the format "X.Y" where X is the original table name and Y is the original field name, but any other solutions would do as well.

P.S.: If it's not clear, when I used "*", I needed columns from both tables, not just one. They are two different tables with different data but with the same column names. (I can't change the names, by the way.)

Comment: Having 100+ columns in a single SQL table is, by itself, indication of possible bad database design.  You should only have a dozen, or most a few dozen, columns in each table.  In that case, writing out each column is not so tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (I don't understand why you want to create a 3rd table where it seems you already have twice the same data):

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` SELECT tl1.* FROM `tl1` INNER JOIN `tl2` ON tl1.urlid = tl2.urlid
```

Comment: I am looking for something like this: "CREATE TABLE `tableName2` SELECT tl1.*,tl2.* FROM `tl1` INNER JOIN `tl2` ON tl1.urlid = tl2.urlid". Need all columns from both tables, not just one table.

Answer (score 0):

First, using [mysql workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).  you need to create the following [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html), by clicking on the desired schema, then right-clicking on view.

It should look something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `schema`.`someView` (
    SELECT t1.* 
    FROM `tl1` as t1 
    JOIN `tl2` as t2
    ON (t1.urlid = t2.urlid)
)
```

Now save it, then reopen it in the "views" tab and you should see this:

```
CREATE VIEW `schema`.`someView` (
    SELECT 
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.col3,
    ...
    FROM `tl1` as t1 
    JOIN `tl2` as t2
    ON (t1.urlid = t2.urlid)
)
```

Now you can an alias to the duplicate columns, then add a `t2.*` to add the rest of the columns

```
CREATE VIEW `schema`.`someView` (
    SELECT 
    t1.id as tl1_id,
    ...
    t2.*
    FROM `tl1` as t1 
    JOIN `tl2` as t2
    ON (t1.urlid = t2.urlid)
)
```

This is the fastest way I know to do this.  Hope it helps.